# Unable to get correct output from python calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple python calculator to calculate dose of a medication.

For a sample weighing 60kg. The dose should be (60*15) divide by 80.
The supposed output should be 11.25 vials.

However, Im getting 7.575757575757576e+27. Please help me out to diagnose the problem here. Thanks

Here is the sample code that i've used.

```
# This is a program to calculate dose for IV Drug X

print('Hello Doctor!')

print('What is your name?')
myName= input()

print('It is good to meet you, ' 'Dr.' +myName)

print('What is the weight of patient?') # Patient weight
ptWeight = input()
print ('Number of vial is ' + str(int((ptWeight)*15) / 80)+ ' vials.')
```

And Here is the output that I got.

```
Hello Doctor!
What is your name?
Brian
It is good to meet you, Dr.Brian
What is the weight of patient?
60
Number of vial is 7.575757575757576e+27 vials.
```

Comment: You multiply the string by 15 which results in "60606060..." and so on. First convert to int, then multiply.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging. Also pay close attention to the types of the values in your code (such as `str` or `int`.

Comment: Also always be careful of what numbers you're using represent. It's not clear in your code how you get from kg to vials. You can explain in comments, or you can assign values to intermediate variables and use them, e.g. `dose_per_kg = 15` or `dose_per_vial = 80`. This lets you see that units cancel, as in `kg * dose / kg = dose` and `dose / (dose / vial) = dose * vial / dose = vials`.

Answer (score 2):

You're multiplying the string

Try this:

```
print ('Number of vial is ' + str(int(ptWeight)*15 / 80)+ ' vials.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying as a sting. Try this instead

```
print('Hello Doctor!')

print('What is your name?')
myName= input()

print('It is good to meet you, ' 'Dr.' +myName)

print('What is the weight of patient?') # Patient weight
ptWeight = int(input())

vitals = round(int((ptWeight)*15) / 80,2)
print ('Number of vial is '+ str(vitals) +' vials.')
```

if you want the value to exact decimal places then use this

```
vitals = int((ptWeight)*15) / 80
```

round() function syntax

```
round(number, places)
```